# Como seleccionar un input según el texto del atributo placeholder para cambiarle dicho texto

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo varios `inputs` que vienen con la misma clase, sin `ID` y sin atributo `name`. Y necesito cambiarle el texto del atributo `placeholder` a partir del texto que trae previamente en dicho atributo.

Por ejemplo estos son los inputs:

```
<input class="form-control underlined" placeholder="Filtrar por nombres" type="text">
<input class="form-control underlined" placeholder="Filtrar por apellidos" type="text">
<input class="form-control underlined" placeholder="Filtrar por Acciones" type="text">
```

Necesito cambiarle el texto del `placeholder` "Filtrar por acciones"

Haciendo lo siguiente, lógicamente cambio el texto a todos los `input`, y no es lo que necesito:

```
$("input.underlined").attr("placeholder", "Nuevo texto");
```

Lo que necesito es algo como esto, que cambie solamente el que tenga un texto dado:

```
$("input[placeholder='Filtrar por Acciones']").attr("placeholder", "Nuevo texto");
```

Esto, por supuesto no funciona de esta forma. Me pueden dar alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Lo pudiera resolver de esta forma:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('underlined')[0].placeholder='nuevo texto';
```

pero además de que todos tienen la misma clase, no conozco la cantidad de `input` que existen, debido a que se generan dinámicamente, por lo que no puedo conocer la posición del `input` a la hora de seleccionar una posición del arreglo. Entonces esta idea que he intentado tampoco me sirve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es así como lo has puesto en la pregunta...

Fijate

```js
$(function() {
  $("#b").on('click', function() {
    $("input[placeholder='Filtrar por Acciones']").attr("placeholder", "Nuevo texto");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input placeholder="Filtrar por Acciones">
<input placeholder="Filtrar por Otra cosa">
<button id="b">cambiar</button>
```

Version sin boton

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[placeholder='Filtrar por Acciones']").attr("placeholder", "Nuevo texto");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input placeholder="Filtrar por Acciones">
<input placeholder="Filtrar por Otra cosa">
```

Comment: No, no es con un botón, necesito que se cambie solo, al cargarse el DOM, de manera que el usuario nunca ve el texto anterior, solo el nuevo

Comment: Y es la diferencia? quiza estas ejecutando el codigo antes que se termina de cargar el DOM. fijate de inculirlo dentro de la estructura que use, o ponerlo al final del html. Asi el codigo se ejecuta luego de cargar los input, sino no funciona por que los elementos no estan creados. saludos.

Comment: Si, tienes razón, es como mismo lo había puesto en la pregunta y como lo pones tu. Ya me funciona, gracias. Parece que era eso mismo el problema, estaba ejecutandolo antes de cargarse los inputs. Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma adicional de hacerlo seria recorrer los elementos de la misma clase con un $.each(), y cambiar el valor cuando encuentre el placeholder que quieres, algo así:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".underlined" ).each(function( index, element ) {
  if($(element).attr('placeholder')==="Filtrar por Acciones"){
    $(element).attr('placeholder',"Nuevo Placeholder")
  }
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="form-control underlined" placeholder="Filtrar por nombres" type="text">
    <input class="form-control underlined" placeholder="Filtrar por apellidos" type="text">
    <input class="form-control underlined" placeholder="Filtrar por Acciones" type="text"> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```